# Replace a word by a word in a string

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a dictionary like below

```
word_dict = {'a': 'a1', 'winter': 'cold', 'summer': 'hot'}
```

and I have a string like this:

```
data = "It's winter not summer. Have a nice day"
```

What I want to do is to replace the word `a by a1`, `winter by cold`, etc in the `data`. I did try to use the below code:

```
for word in word_dict:
    data = data.replace(word, word_dict[word])
```

But it fails because it replaces the substring (substring of the `data`, not the word). Infact, the word `Have` is replace by `Ha1ve`.

The result should be:

```
data = "It's cold not hot. Have a1 nice day"
```

Comment: You want regular expressions and the `\b` (=word boundary) thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `re.sub` . `\b` word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character. We need to use word boundary to match an exact word string or otherwise, it would match also the `a` in `day`

```
>>> word_dict = {'a': 'a1', 'winter': 'cold', 'summer': 'hot'}
>>> data = "It's winter not summer. Have a nice day"
>>> for word in word_dict:
        data = re.sub(r'\b'+word+r'\b', word_dict[word], data)


>>> data
"It's cold not hot. Have a1 nice day"
```

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple ways to achieve this, apart from regular expressions:

```
ldata = data.split(' ') #splits by whitespace characters
res = []
for i in ldata:
    if i in word_dict:
        res.append(word_dict[i])
    else:
        res.append(i)
final = ' '.join(res)
```

regular expression solution is more practical and fit to what you want, but list.split() and string.join() methods come in handy sometimes. :)

Comment: using .keys is lnot needed and inefficient . Just use in word_dict

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. :)
p.s. can you provide any reference/explanation to it's inefficiency? i have heard it but don't know the actual reason. :)

Comment: in python 2 you build a list and do a linear scan so it is becomes an `0(n)` operation as opposed to 0(1),  in python 3 you have an extra function call creating a dictview

Comment: Not really good solution as the text may contains multiple space and this can destroy the space after replacing. For example, consider the case I have the text like `This is a _______ example` (consider _ as a space in my example as Stackoverflow does not allow me to comment with multiple spaces) and your method will destroy the spaces between `a` and `example`

Comment: Nice point, i think i was able to solve it by replacing split() with split(' '). now extra spaces are also items in the list. So when we use join there will also be in the final result. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use split with dict.get and split on `" "` to keep the correct spacing:

```
from string import punctuation

print(" ".join([word_dict.get(x.rstrip(punctuation), x) for x in data.split(" ")]))
It's cold not hot. Have a1 nice day
```

We also need to strip punctuation so `summer.` matches `summer` etc...

Some timings show even with splitting and stripping the non regex approach is still over twice as fast:

```
In [18]: %%timeit                                                              data = "It's winter not summer. Have a nice day"
for word in word_dict:
        data = re.sub(r'\b'+word+r'\b', word_dict[word], data)
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.2 µs per loop

In [19]: timeit " ".join([word_dict.get(x.rstrip(punctuation), x) for x in data.split(" ")])
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.52 µs per loop
```

Comment: Very nice use of dictionary.get default value. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator inside the `join()` function :

```
>>> word_dict = {'a': 'a1', 'winter': 'cold', 'summer': 'hot'}
>>> data = "It's winter not summer. Have a nice day"
>>> ' '.join(word_dict[j] if j in word_dict else j for j in data.split())
"It's cold not summer. Have a1 nice day"
```

with splitting the data you can search in its words then use a simple comprehension to replace the specific words .